# Is there a pragma or attribute to avoid an unused debug type being eliminated by GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

Consider the below code, by default GCC avoids producing debug symbol output for types that are unused.

```
union my_type_A { int _; };

int main() {}
```

Option -fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types results in a significant amount of space overhead as the real project is much more complicated.

Currently, I work it around by adding an unused function:

```
void foo(my_type_A) {}
```

So, the type can be used in GDB. My WAR seems not that straightforward. Is there a pragma or attribute to avoid an unused debug type being eliminated by GCC? Thanks.

[Ref: GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)